# Unable to build PlusClient

Tags: android, google-plus

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
            OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 7;
        private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
        private PlusClient mPlusClient;
        private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
        private String TAG = "GmailLogin";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
            if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
                GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
            } else {

                 mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                 .setVisibleActivities( "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                 "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();


                mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

                Button signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
                signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                mConnectionResult
                                        .startResolutionForResult(
                                                MainActivity.this,
                                                REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                                // Try connecting again.
                                mConnectionResult = null;
                                mPlusClient.connect();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
            // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
            mConnectionResult = result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR
                    && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
            Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
        }

        }
```

I cannot compile this code because it says:

> PlusClient.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

at

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setVisibleActivities( "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
        "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
```

also in `onConnected()`

I get `null` for `accountName`

```
String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
```

Comment: `Google+ SDK`?? I am using `google-play-services.jar` currently.

Comment: I couldn't find `Google+ SDK` in `Android SDK Manager`. Can you provide me with a link and a guide would be great.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear the Google+ SDK is within Google Play Services. Did you update Google Play Services to the latest version (current rev 5)?

Comment: Also, did you consider adding the Google Play Services Library instead of the .jar file?

Answer (score 10):

If anybody still has this problem: the PlayClient is deprecated now.
The "new" way to go is described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addApi(Plus.API, plusOptions)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is because PlayClient is deprecated now, as Luigi04 states.

As a work around, I got this working by downgrading the play services version in the gradle dependencies to `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'`, as stated here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637059/2161698

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, the issue was that I was using old version of Google Play Service. So please update it to the latest version. Remember that new version is downloaded in sdk folder. If you earlier have imported google-play-services to your workspace you must delete it and add new version

Answer (score 0):

The jar by itself cannot be use. The entire google play services lib project needs to be imported ie copied from SDK.

See step 5 of [Google+ Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android):

```
5. Import the Google Play Services library project.

Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
Select Browse.... Enter <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/.
Select google-play-services_lib. Click Finish to import.
```

Comment: You can just do this in gradle:     compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.+'

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html, You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied to your development workspace—you should not reference the library directly from the Android SDK directory.