# can not find symbol class Builder

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using loginActivity in android.

**ERROR**

```
can not find symbol class Builder
```

I have also imported the file: `com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient`

**Error on this line**

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
```

This is auto generated file from template.
What could be the reason for this error?

**EDIT**

I am using android studio

minSdkVersion 11

targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: you know that if major part of version of library changes it can break the contract? please do not change library to higher version without reading the docs

Comment: @Selvin : I didn't use any thing. I have just created basic template for loginActivity

Comment: Could you add to the question from where? Eclipse or android studio and which version of as or adt? The Builder class was there but I don't know in what version of gms and since google not versioning docs of gms is hard to say it

Comment: @Selvin : I am new to android dev. I don't know how to check adt version

Comment: Adt is a eclipse plugin, if you are using Android studio then you don't have adt so you shouldn't worry about it. Anyway if is the newest (1.0.0) version of as then template is broken as it not support newest version of gms...  You can try to change gms to older version in dependency in gradle file

Comment: Right now it's `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` in dependencies in gradle file

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'` < change it to 5.0.89 (if you had such version in `SDKPATH\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services`)

Comment: Now, I am getting some weird error: `Attribute 'theme' has already been defined`

Comment: This error came from PlusBaseActivity.java which was created automatically by Android Studio when it created a List Fragment. I ended up to delete file to get rid of the error, I didn't use Google+'s +1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved in my project by downgrading play-services to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

in dependencies in gradle file.

Comment: Worked for me. Weird that the code generated by default LoginActivity would have this problem...

Comment: How to change this in eclipse?

Comment: And for when you struggle to use the new API because documentation is scarce, this helps: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-plus-login-example/ and http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Answer (score 8):

It is not available because it is deprecated. Use GoogleApiClient instead.
[Start integrating Google+](http://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) : This is the official documentation for implementing Google+ client in your Android app for login and other requirements. Please follow this and not the auto-generated code from Android studio (until the code gets updated with newer implementation).

**P.S.** The other answer suggests to use older version of PlusClient, which is a wrong approach. You should be using newer code Instead of using older play services.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your approach a little bit deeper? The code posted in the answer is automatically generated by Android Studio, so it could be great to provide a better alternative.

Comment: Too bad that Android studio hasn't updated the auto-generated code. Google has changed the implementation a while back. I would advise to not use the studio generated code and implement yourself following the documentation. I have updated the answer with the link.