# PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this) cannot be resolved to a type in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-plus

I am using PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this) for google+.:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
    .build();
```

I got error message "cannot be resolved to a type".

It have solve in android studio IDE. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389192/can-not-find-symbol-class-builder/27637059#27637059)

How to fix this error in eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This metod no longer works. Now you need to instantiate google api like this

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
        .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

You can change **Plus.SCOPESCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN** to  **SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE** to retreive different information from google+ account. See here [Plus Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus.html)

You also need to implements *GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks* and                                   *GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener* in your activity declaration.