# cannot find symbol class "Builder"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have recently downloaded `Android Studio`, I thought it has more features than `eclipse`.

I created a new project, with a log in activity, but it seems there is an error with the activity :![enter image description here][1]

```
**Error:(78, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Builder
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.**
```

```html
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;


    // This is the helper object that connects to Google Play Services.
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize the PlusClient connection.
        // Scopes indicate the information about the user your application will be able to access.
        mPlusClient =
                new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                        Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
    }
```

Comment: Possibly similar issue is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108235/unable-to-build-plusclient)

Answer (score 8):

It is a duplicate of [Unable to build PlusClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108235/unable-to-build-plusclient) and [can not find symbol class Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389192/can-not-find-symbol-class-builder/)

For Quick Reference:
The issue is that the PlayClient is deprecated now but the template still uses the old way.

Thus, you can:

1. Change the play services version in the gradle dependencies (`build.gradle`) from `com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87`  to  `com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71`.

**OR**

2. Use the new way as described here:http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html i.e, instead of creating the instance of `PlusClient.Builder` create an instance of  `GoogleApiClient.Builder` as shown:

   ```
   // Builds single client object that connects to Drive and Google+

    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addApi(Drive.API)
           .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
           .addApi(Plus.API, plusOptions)
           .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .build();
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't download the Google Play services yet, if so then download them from SDK Manager -> Extras -> Google Play Services.

And if they are already downloaded then you should do

step 5 of [Google+ Quickstart:](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)

5. Import the Google Play Services library project.

Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
Select Browse.... Enter /extras/google/google_play_services/.
Select google-play-services_lib. Click Finish to import.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: When we use templates in Android studio they add play-services as a dependency, and if they don't even then we don't need to import play services. We just need to add compile statement in ``build.gradle`` e.g. ``com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87``.Can you please explain your answer?