# error: cannot find symbol class Builder

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I'm following this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/face-detection-in-android-with-google-play-services/ step by step.

Nevertheless, i'm facing some errors that i can't solve through stackoverflow.

the piece of code with troubles is the following:

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.image01);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setTrackingEnabled(false)
        .build();


Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


//create a frame from the bitmap and run face detection on the frame
Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
SparseArray<Face> faces = detector.detect(frame);

TextView faceCountView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.face_count);
faceCountView.setText(faces.size() + "faces detected");

detector.release();
```

and i'm getting those errors:

> C:\Users\XXX\FaceDetectionDemo\app\src\main\java\com\example\XXX\facedetectiondemo\MainActivity.java
>   Error:(40, 49) error: cannot find symbol class Builder Error:(51, 21)
>   error: cannot find symbol class Face Error:(51, 43) error: cannot find
>   symbol method detect(Frame) Error:(56, 17) error: cannot find symbol
>   method release() Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

build.gradle has the correct dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

I tried with this entry [cannot find symbol class "Builder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668569/cannot-find-symbol-class-b)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV43s.png)uilder?rq=1 but it doesn't work

[SDK TOOLS INSTALLED]

Comment: update you google play service lib...  dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
}

Comment: but then i get another error. Even when the lib is actualized.

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1 
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/XXX/FaceDetectionDemo/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: And when i try to 'update' (because it's already updated) .I get :

Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Then I found this solution; it worked for me: you must delete the library.

Change this:

```
import android.media.FaceDetector;
```

to:

```
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;
```