# Error in code from documentation google plus

Tags: android, sdk, google-plus

I use code from [this manual](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) and I copy this part of code in my `onCreate()` method. But word **Builder** has red color (this mean error).

```
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", 
                                  "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .build();
```

**UPD** This part of dependencies from `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
...
```

}

Comment: Check if you are including right library and right version (where Builder() constructor has three argument).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108235/unable-to-build-plusclient    hope it helps.

Comment: error dont in arguments - http://joxi.ru/ZrJVlnVhWMMWrj

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you might be using new version of Goggle Play [which is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)

Comment: One more thing... in case libraries are in place clean and build your application that might help.

Comment: write as answer and I check it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am trying to say is that you might be using new version of Google Play [which is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108235/unable-to-build-plusclient) help you out.